# How long should it take my pet to empty their bladder?

Tags: health

Changes in urination patterns can be an indicator of illness. I was wondering how long should it normally take for my pet to empty their bladder?

Answer (score 1):

If your pet is a mammal who weighs more then 3kg (6.6lbs) it should take about 21 seconds (*plus or minus 13 seconds*) to empty their bladder.  A team from Georgia Tech just won the [2015 Ig Nobel Prize in Physics](http://www.improbable.com/ig/winners/#ig2015) for their research as announced in the [BBC news](http://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-34278595)  the full research is published [here](http://www.pnas.org/content/111/33/11932.full)

[image]

Be aware though, smaller animals like Rats can urinate in a fraction of a second.